# Choose option in suffering?

Tags: suffering

Hair fall suffering..

Breakup suffering.

Self criticism suffering.

Separation suffering .

Not to  get what is want .

....................................................................................................

Option:

1.run from suffering.(escape from suffering)( drink alcohol)

2.face suffering..

3.Effort to overcome suffering.

4.Accept what is suffering..

Your opinion

Comment: Are you asking what is the right way from the listed options?

Comment: You are right.. Choose option

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The one and only option which closer to the one and only answer is

4.Accept what it is.

But `Accept` what? what's the meaning of `what it is` are the things that we should understand first.

First of all to `Accept` we need to understand how the world behave. Answer to that is `paticcasamuppadaya`. This is a very highlevel answer so you need to find out what's the meaning of `paticcasamuppadaya`. Once you realize that -> you would know that everything in the world behave as a result of a cause. 
Cause -> Result. So when you understand (realize) this the nature of the world, you have to accept the flows (way of things happening) of the world.

Next let's see why we have to accept it `as it is`. Why we can't change it. Why we can't apply new causes and change it to the way we want it to be.

As you know

1. Causes -> Results.
2. Causes + new Causes -> Some other results ; (We add new results)

If I take an example : breakup suffering -> let's assume

1. Girl want to stop the affair -> Breakup
2. Girl want to stop + Boy pleads not to do (or buy some expensive gifts ) -> No Breakup

Now in the second step the new causes (pleading or buying new gifts) are caused by the greed (love) of the boy to that girl. So that greediness will cause the boy another results which is not good. In buddhism Raga, Dvesha, Moha (greed, hate, delusion) are the causes for bad results. So when trying to change the flows of the things happening in the world, always done based on greed, hate or delusion, which will results in a new bad things. Because everything is Causes -> Results. (This is what explains in the `paticcasamuppada`)

Understanding this nature of the world explains in dhamma `yampiccan na labhathi thampi dukkhan` -> `Not getting what one desires`. This is also meant by the `Anicca`. A very closer word to this meaning in english is `insatiable`

**Note:** Most of the people thing `Anicca` means `impermanence` which is not true. Actually impermanence is a subset of `anicca`. I'm not going to change what people think about this, because nothing is `icca` -> `(getting what one desire : opposite of anicca)` Everything is `anicca` in this world. This impermanence misinterpretation is a result of sanskrit translation (which buddha advised not to translate to sanskrit )

Below are the proof for my points from the pali cannon. And also please note there are some conflicts / mistakes in english translations. I've highlighted that in the latter part.

Below is the core of buddhism which extracted from [Saccabihanga sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.141.piya.html)

> What is meant by not getting what one desires, that too is suffering?
>   To beings subject to birth there comes desire: 'O might we not be
>   subject to birth, and birth not come to us.' But this cannot be
>   attained by mere desiring. So not getting what one desires, that too,
>   is suffering. To beings subject to aging there comes the desire: 'O
>   might we not be subject to aging, and aging not come to us...' (as
>   before). To beings subject to disease there comes the desire: 'O might
>   we not be subject to disease and disease not come to us...' To beings
>   subject to death there comes the desire: 'O might we not be subject to
>   death and death not come to us...' To beings subject to sorrow,
>   lamentation, suffering, misery, and despair there comes the desire: 'O
>   might we not be subject to sorrow, lamentation, suffering, misery, and
>   despair, and sorrow, lamentation, suffering, misery, and despair not
>   come to us.' But this cannot be attained by merely desiring. So not
>   getting what one desires that too is suffering.

But in above translation it is written with the word too (that too is suffering). But in pali cannon there's nothing like that. It just say, not getting what one desires (yampiccan na labhathi thampi dukkhan).

Therefore accept things as it is, trying to change things won't give you positive results. And also this doesn't mean that when don't save someone when he is about to hit by a bus even though when you have a chance to save him. As I mentioned earlier if the thoughts are based on greed, hate or delusion then there's a problem. If your thoughts are against those then go for it (this will also become useless as it keep you in `sansara` It's a different topic to talk about). With the understanding of `insatiable` state of the world, trying to changing things will be decreased.

Comment: Bro you give great answer .. Accept

Comment: If you accept this is as the answer, you may mark this as the answer by clicking the right mark on the left of the answer :)

Comment: Beware that "*anicca* doesn't mean impermanent" is a controversial theory (i.e. a lot of people think that theory is wrong). In [this comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/33629/is-impermanence-a-bad-translation-of-anicca#comment57496_33633) Isuru seemed to accept that "anicca" doesn't mean "an+iccha", instead it means "a+nicca",

Answer (score 1):

According to SN 56.11 e.g. as summarised on page 46 of [this analysis](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.1-Dhammacakka-Pavattana-S-s56.11-piya.pdf):

> 1. Suffering should be **known**
> 2. Craving should be **abandoned**
> 3. Nirvana should be **realized**
> 4. The path should be **cultivated**

I think that means something like,

1. Experience suffering (or sufferings plural)
2. Understand that suffering co-arises with (and ceases with) with craving and attachment
3. Abandon (don't attach to) cravings

Perhaps "accept what is suffering" isn't a good description of what to do. More specifically something like, "accept without craving so that suffering doesn't arise".

Comment: Are you saying  .suffering dependence

Comment: Suffering is "dependently originated" -- by understanding how and why it arises (e.g. craving, also conceit), you should avoid its arising -- and, by choosing not to attach to cravings and so on when they arise, allow suffering to cease when suffering co-arises with cravings. There's also the opposite i.e. "skilful virtue" (doing good things well) which causes "no remorse", from which may arise "joy", etc.

Comment: Thanks  guide suffering more deeply